# Why is strapi v4 only rendering the first 25 articles? Next.js - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

I am having the strangest bug with strapi v4.

The stack is react and next.js

I've implemented a dynamic pagination with the format /page/[slug]
It's working almost flawlessly, except for one fatal flaw. Even though it is pulling all 200 something articles and rendering them on the /page/1 - /page/22, only the first 25 articles route to the respective article page. the 26th and so on return 404 with the slug not found from the api. Even though all 200 cards with slugs, images, descriptions, and publish dates render: [image: Card Image]

They still don't lead to a page after the 26th with the following error
`​GET http://localhost:3000/articles/lorem 404 (Not Found)`

Nothing in the strapi documentation mentions 25 or an article cap. What am I missing here? I'll drop the render calls below.

This is the code for /article/page/[slug]

```
  const res = await fetchStrapi(
    `/articles?pagination[page]=1&pagination[pageSize]=12`
  );

  const pageCount = res.meta.pagination.pageCount;
  const paths = Array.from({ length: pageCount }, (_, i) => i + 1);
  const pathsString = paths.map((path) => path.toString());

  return {
    paths: pathsString.map((path) => ({
      params: {
        slug: path,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const page = params.slug || 1;
  const articles = await fetchStrapi(
    `/articles?pagination[page]=${page}&pagination[pageSize]=12&populate[image][fields][0]=name&populate[image][fields][1]=url`
  );

  const numberOfArticles = articles.meta.pagination.pageCount;

  return {
    props: {
      articles,
      page,
      numberOfArticles,
    },
    revalidate: 3600,
  };
}
```

and for /article/[slug]

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const articlesRes = await fetchStrapi(`/articles`);

  return {
    paths: articlesRes.data.map((article) => ({
      params: {
        slug: article.attributes.slug,
      },
    })),

    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const articlesRes = await fetchStrapi('/articles', {
    populate: ['image', 'author', 'author.image', 'keywords'],
    filters: {
      slug: params.slug,
    },
  });

  const categoriesRes = await fetchStrapi('/categories');

  return {
    props: {
      article: articlesRes.data[0],
      categories: categoriesRes,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the configuration in your strapi backend.
In the file api.js inside your config you can change the default limit:

```
module.exports = {
      rest: {
        defaultLimit: 25, //change this
        maxLimit: 100,
        withCount: true,
      },
    };
```

Then, restart your server and you got it.